# How to forward port to a host side?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, 0ad

I want to forward the UDP port 20595 on the host side in order to play a multiplayer game :

[image]

Yet I am not on my server IP, I am really new to this. But I know from this question that I have to do something like forwarding from xx.x.x.xxx:xxxxx -> xxx.xxx.xx.x:20595 or xx.x.x.xxx:20595

Comment: Do you have a router?  Normally you would set port forwarding on a router.

Comment: @Terrance Hmm I have this [high-end fixed and wireless modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freebox)

Comment: You would access the setup pages in that device to configure the port forwarding to your system.  I am not familiar with that device.  You might need to check their support site if they have one.

Comment: Is there a solution to this? I want to do the same, have no idea how...